# Not all models in collection being deleted

Tags: backbone.js, model-view-controller

I have a collection that I'm appending to. On my app, I destroy all the models when I log out - with this piece of code :

```
logout: function(event) {
    $.post('./logout');
    App.Contacts.each(function (contact){
        console.log(contact);
        contact.destroy();
    });
}
```

The problem is that not all the models are being deleted. If i press the logout button a couple more time to trigger this function, they eventually end up getting deleted.
The console complains that they are undefined - so it doesn't have a handle to it.

What could possibly be going on?

Comment: Do you need to destroy the models server-side as well as client-side?

Comment: no - just the client side. At the moment, I'm using another jquery hack. I find myself doing things like this all the time when I run into these problems.

Comment: Then use `collection.reset()` and listen for the `'reset'` event from the collection to clean up the views.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [reset](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset). Calling `collection.reset()` without passing any models as arguments will empty the entire collection.

Try :

```
logout: function(event) {
    $.post('./logout');
    App.Contacts.reset();
}
```

Comment: That seems to work by removing the models, but the views are still there

Answer (score 1):

If you want to destroy all of them in order to fire `destroy` or `remove` events (which you won't get from `reset`), you can try using the `invoke` method.

For example,

```
logout: function(event) {
    $.post('./logout');
    App.Contacts.invoke('destroy');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, every time you destroy a model, the length of collection will change, that may casue some problems, so if you want to handle it properly, use:

`App.Contacts.reset();`

Just as what Niranjan Borawake said.